# what is the problem with last printf. It doesnt print the string with space and symbols

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    char ch;
    char s[100];
    char sen[100];
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    scanf("%s", s);
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);
    printf("%c\n", ch);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s\n", sen);  
    return 0;
}
```

//input

- C
- Language
- Welcome To C!!

i didn't get the output for the last printf. what could be the wrong here?

Comment: What output _did_ you get? When analysing such problems, it's useful to print quotation marks or other delimiters around your strings, e.g. `printf("s: '%s'\n", s)`, so that you can detect what exactly the input was. Your problem here is that you mix various `scanf` formats that treat white-space and new-lines differently. As a rule, `scanf` is not a good way to read interactive, line-wise input.

Comment: Change `"%[^\n]%*c"` to `" %[^\n]%*c"` (notice the SP) and you should be fine...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Suggesting `" %[^\n]%*c"` has a weakness like suggesting [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).  Both risk buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Input is

`"C\n"`, `"Language\n"`, `"Welcome To C!!\n"`.

`scanf("%c", &ch);` reads `"C"`.  `"\nLanguage\nWelcome To C!!\n"` remains.  `"%c"` reads/saves 1 character.

`scanf("%s", s);` reads `"\nLanguage"`. `"\nWelcome To C!!\n"` remains. `"%s"` reads/discards leading white-space and reads/saves unlimited non-white-space characters, then appends a *null character* to `s`.

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);` reads *nothing*. `"\nWelcome To C!!\n"` remains.  `"%[^\n]%*c"` stops  immediately because the first available character is a `'\n'` and that is not in the scanset  `[^\n]`.  `sen` unchanged.

> what is the problem with last printf

`printf("%s\n", sen);` attempts to print from the unassigned `sen` array leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

> what could be the wrong here?

**Failure to check the return value of `scanf()` in 3 places**

With `if (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen) != 1) puts("Error");`, It would become clear, nothing was read.

**Using `"%s"` and `"%[^\n]"` without a width**

`scanf("%s", s);` risks input overflow.  Use a width like `scanf("%99s", s);` with `char s[100];`

---

Could also change code to consume leading white-space.

```
// scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sen);
//         v---- Note space.
if (scanf(" %99[^\n]%*c", sen) != 1) {
  puts("Error");
}
```

Even better, stop using `scanf()` and use `fgets()` for all user input.  Read into a *string* and then parse.